# camparing frames from video by matlab

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, graphics

I have this problem. I should to make **pdf**  from video (turning pages of book) . So I try choose to every single page from video (without OCR).  My plan is: in `o{}` are saved all frames from video.  `n`, `p` are variables for choosing frames for comparing.  First frame is automatically saved to `c{1}`. later I compare 2. and 3. frame. if they are same I compare 3. and 4. etc. while there will be 2 different frames(during turning pages every frame is different). ) Now I am finding two same frames (it is time while I am moving hand for turn next page) and save it to `c{2}`. changing of resolution and converting to BW are for saving hardware (processor). can you help me? I have problem with copying frames to `c` there is my code.

```
n=2; 
p=3; 
i=1;
c{1}=o{1};
all=136;
while p <= all
        G=im2bw(o{n},0.4); 
        BW1 = imresize(G, 0.1);
        D=im2bw(o{p},0.4);
        BW2= imresize(D, 0.1);
        a=compare(BW1, BW2)
    if a>2
        n=p;
        p=p+1;
    else

    while true
    n=p;
    p=p+1;
    G=im2bw(o{n},0.4); 
    BW1 = imresize(G, 0.1);
    D=im2bw(o{p},0.4);
    BW2= imresize(D, 0.1);
    a=compare(BW1, BW2)


if a>2;  
  end
        end
            i=i+1;
            c{i}=BW2;
            n=p;
            p=p+1;

    end
end
```

and here is function compare:

```
    function NumPixels = compare( BW1 , BW2 )
bothTrue = BW1 & BW2;
NumPixels = sum(bothTrue(:));
end
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is it related to having a copy of your loop in an infinite loop inside your loop (what's up with that)?

Comment: i always have in "c" only first one image although if is very benevolent...

Comment: What range of values do you get for `a`? 2 pixels seems like an unrealistically low threshold.

Comment: in a are numbers cca 12000. a=NumPixels. yes it is unrealistic i will change it. but i can´t understand why in c is only one image, when a>>>2..

Comment: Er, because when `a>2` you do nothing except skip to the next frame (instead of falling into the inner infinite loop that would error out before you ever assigned to `c` anyway). You know how `if...else...` works, right?

Comment: but it is not classic IF. "IF" is there because i needed to use DO WHILE and i found that in matlab DO WHILE syntax is:              while true
  %code here
  if save_rig == A(n); break; end
end

Comment: break was missing there. thank you for your help